# How can I load a single subcomponent quickly during development?

Tags: angular, angular2-components

I'm working on an Angular 5 project where I need to build out a component that is buried deep in a ui.   My workflow ends up being make a change, click 5 levels deep into the interface, view the change, Repeat.  I need to shorten that loop to be more like make change, refresh, operate the component.

How would I create a separate 'sandbox' url entry point where I can just load the component I'm working on in isolation to troubleshoot its events/css in one click?

Other solutions appreciated.  I'm potentially missing a common workflow here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to create a special route for a test page, that simply display a "component-page"
Then you write your target component into the component-page

```
 <page-test>
       <the-component-you-want-to-test> </the-component-you-want-to-test>
 </page-test>
```